# Verb similar to "synchronize" but not for time

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs, word-usage

I am looking for a word that describes adjusting status to conform another. Let us say the status of the account is active but in our system shows inactive. *Synchronize* [describes](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/synchronize) the situation with respect to time.

Can I say "I conformed the status" if I want to say that I adjusted the system status to be active like the account status?

Answer (score 6):

> if I want to say that I adjusted the system status to be active like the account status?

How did it end up that it was not like the account status?

If it's because the account status changes, then *synchronised* is the perfect word because it does indeed relate to time; the changes that happen over time.

Otherwise:

*Reconciled*; meaning to bring two things into agreement.

*Coordinate*; referring to the two together, you don't coordinate one thing, but you can coordinate a pair whether by changing both, or by only changing one.

*Rectify*; considering one to be incorrect, and hence the adjustment is a rectification.

*Harmonise*; as per *coordinate*.

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with synchronize? It doesn't just apply to time.

Oxford Dictionaries give as a non-time meaning  *Their version failed to synchronize with the police version*

Comment: Indeed. Synchronising is often used when systems reconcile an offline datastore (eg mailbox) with an online one.

Answer (score 1):

You could say "reconciled" or "put in sync".

Comment: What's 'sync' if not short for 'synchronize'?

Comment: @WS2 Nothing. sir. I see nothing wrong with synchronise, personally - so I provide a non-literal alternative as well. And as most of us are in IT in some capacity I would imagine synchronise will seem reasonable to many.

Answer (score 1):

How about you "[aligned](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/align?show=0&t=1392129132)" the two statuses (or brought them into alignment):

> to arrange things so that they form a line or are in proper position;
>
> to change (something) so that it agrees with or matches something
>   else

Answer (score 1):

**Harmonise** (or *harmonize*) means to make (one thing) compatible with (another); ([ref](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/harmonise), #4).

The word has come into common usage with respect to reconciling or coordinating laws and tariffs, as described in [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonisation_of_law) on the harmonization of law.

[This document](http://ec.europa.eu/internal_market/accounting/docs/com-95-508/com-95-508_en.pdf) discusses the harmonization of accounting practices.

The [Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/harmonization.html) generalizes this to be

> the adjustment of differences and inconsistencies among different measurements, methods, procedures, schedules, specifications, or systems to make them uniform or mutually compatible.

Another source has a similar definition:

> Generally, harmonisation can be defined as “actions or processes that through matching and blending bring about agreement, reconciliation or standardization”.

*Harmonisation* is also used to describe the reconciliation of dat or information, as [this source](http://www.theseusproject.eu/wiki/Data_harmonization) indicates:

> Harmonization is to create the possibility to combine data from heterogeneous sources into integrated, consistent and unambiguous information products, in a way that is of no concern to the end-user.

*Harmonise* has become a buzzword in some circles, especially within the European Union and its governing bodies.  So...

**Unify**

If you want to use something a little closer to the vernacular, you can try **unify**, which means to combine, merge, fuse or coalesce, to resolve conflicts and bring together into a single or common framework.

But I think *coordinate* or *synchronize* will be understood very well by anyone when it comes to unifying the common view of what the status of a project might be.

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself: You **adjusted** the status.

Another word that would work is *match*, as in

> The status now **matches** the other one

Comment: if it's not only about a status, i believe leveling or equalizing would work as well.

Comment: *Adjust* does not necessarily mean conformity. I might adjust it to something different. *match* is an option, but I need it as a verb. Can I say *I matched the status*. How common and acceptable is that?